# Can d(x²-y²) form π bonds with other p- or d-orbitals?

Tags: bond

$d_{x^2-y^2}$ doesn't change sign when transformation of $x\rightarrow-x$ or when similar transformation with $y$ is made. However no such thing occurs with any p- or d-orbital. Thus, can we say that $d_{x^2-y^2}$ don't form $π$ bonds with any p/d-orbitals?

Comment: You can say that, but it won't be correct.

Comment: Likewise, $p_x$ doesn't change sign upon the transformation of $y→−y$.

Comment: A p orbital in the x-y plane centered on the $y=x$ line oriented orthogonal to that line has the correct symmetry to interact with your orbital, for example.